# How to create this type of panels in Android?

Tags: android, panels

I've seen this type of panels (white ones with the shadow border at the bottom) and I would like to use them in my apps.

https://lh6.ggpht.com/i_RUUvI7G2UM1eBn5hAcJQvqK_K1tHMiw7ynAc4hwwUD1_J1g03MkMBaFu0n5jA2YA=h900-rw

What kind of panels are and How can I create them?

Thanks in advance

Comment: looks like popup window to me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**/drawable/panel_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Bottom 3dp Shadow -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

        <solid android:color="#C7C6C5" />
        <corners android:radius="4dp" />

    </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- White Top color -->
    <item android:bottom="4px">

        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

        <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        <corners android:radius="4dp" />


        </shape>

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**/layout/test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/panel_bg"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Hello world"
                android:textColor="#cccccc"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1234567890"
                android:textColor="#cccccc"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/panel_bg"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:text="Hellllooo"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ashkdhakhd"
                android:textColor="#38B6AB"
                android:textSize="32sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**or you can create custom listView**

Comment: Thanks, the shadow of the panel is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting different themes. And select the one you need for the application.

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing but a Custom Dialog box. You can make this kind of dialog boxes through this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/), And you need a good graphic designer to make this kind of design.

Comment: That type of dialog boxes, panels are in many apps, so I think it will be a predefined type.